# The Hard Drive only show two partition when install ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation

Why When I start install Ubuntu using CD Drive (windows 7 has installed),the Hard Drive only show two partition..?
whereas I have four partition and 40GB unallocated (i planned this for install Ubuntu) on my ASUS N43SL notebook..

shown when install Ubuntu :
100 MB System,
150 GB (windows 7) and
590 GB (40 GB not shown)

Shown on windows 7:
100 MB System,
150 GB Drive C,
194 GB Drive E,
220 GB Drive F,
100 GB DRIVE G,

Comment: Are you using Dynamic Disks in Windows?

Comment: yes,i'm using dynamic disk,, how to convert dynamic disk to basic disk without losing data..? i'm using windows7 ultimate 64 bit..

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic disks is a proprietary extension which only Windows understands, you're right that you need to convert such disks back to basic disks to be able to install any non-Windows OS.

Here are the [instructions on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/65939/converting-dynamic-to-basic-disk) - I can't confirm they're working as I usually don't keep Windows on my laptops.

Make sure you have a backup of your data in any case.

Comment: is there an easier and safer way..? i tried install using wubi(file ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso in the same folder with wubi.exe),why after reboot and go to the desktop ubuntu, the installation never completed..?